# A word for "impressed surprise"?

Tags: single-word-requests

> She picked up the phone. "Hello?" "Hi Emily. It's me, Tim. The guy you met from the party. I'm just returning the call." "Oh, hi Tim. Wow..." she said with ________. "I didn't think you'd call..."

Comment: What is the meaning of "impressed surprise"? When and in what context do you use "impressed surprise"? Just when the guy you met at the party calls?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use "astonished" if you remove "with"

> "Oh, hi Tim. Wow..." she said, astonished. "I didn't think you'd call..."

From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astonish):

> to cause a feeling of great wonder or surprise in (someone)